# When is the destination view controller initialized during a segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm attempting to write a protocol and a custom UIStoryboardSegue class that will allow me to easily implement custom transitions in my UIViewControllers:

```
public protocol TransitionController
{
    var transitionDurationIn:  CFTimeInterval { get }
    var transitionDurationOut: CFTimeInterval { get }
    func prepareTransitionIn()
    func prepareTransitionOut()
    func performTransitionIn(finished: @escaping () -> Void)
    func performTransitionOut(finished: @escaping () -> Void)
}

class JFTransitionControllerSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let defaultTransitionDuration : CFTimeInterval = 1.5

        if let dvc = self.destination as? TransitionController {
            dvc.prepareTransitionIn()
        }
        else {
            // Default transition
            self.destination.view.alpha = 0
        }
        if let svc = self.source as? TransitionController {
            svc.prepareTransitionOut()
            svc.performTransitionOut(){ () in
                if let dvc = self.destination as? TransitionController {
                    dvc.performTransitionIn(){ () in
                        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Default transition for the destination controller
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: defaultTransitionDuration, animations: {
                        self.destination.view.alpha = 1
                    }) { (Finished) in
                        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Default transition for the source controller
            UIView.animate(withDuration: defaultTransitionDuration, animations: {
                self.source.view.alpha = 0
            }) { (Finished) in
                if let dvc = self.destination as? TransitionController {
                    dvc.performTransitionIn(){ () in
                        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Default transition for the destination controller
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: defaultTransitionDuration, animations: {
                        self.destination.view.alpha = 1
                    }) { (Finished) in
                        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestController: UIViewController, TransitionController {
    @IBOutlet weak var form_username: UITextField!

    // MARK: - TransitionController Protocol

    var transitionDurationIn  : CFTimeInterval {return 1.0}
    var transitionDurationOut : CFTimeInterval {return 1.0}

    func prepareTransitionIn()
    {
        //self.view.alpha = 0 // no fade in if you uncomment
        form_username.alpha = 0 // nil
    }
    func prepareTransitionOut()
    {
        self.view.alpha = 1 // works
    }
    func performTransitionIn(finished: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.transitionDurationIn, animations: {
            //self.view.alpha = 1 // no fade in if you uncomment
            self.form_username.alpha = 1 // nil, crashes
        }) { (Finished) in
            finished()
        }
    }
    func performTransitionOut(finished: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.transitionDurationOut, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 0 // fades out correctly
        }) { (Finished) in
            finished()
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, you just implement the protocol in any UIViewController you want, then make a segue of class JFTransitionControllerSegue. In the `performTransitionIn` function, you can just do something like `UIView.animate` and change the alpha or whatever you like. The problem I'm having is that the destination segue simply pops up instead of transitioning in properly. From what I can tell while debugging it isn't fully initialized - IBOutlet variables are nil, but the controller itself isn't. Is this a bad design pattern, or am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

A view controller being initialised is one event. It's view being loaded is another.

The `view` property of a view controller is loaded lazily and the outlets are built and connected at that point. That's why `viewDidLoad()` is a thing.

If you want the view to be ready for you, you can call `loadViewIfNeeded()` on the view controller first.

Answer (score 0):

Misdiagnosed the problem...the destination controller was loaded, but I had forgotten to add the destination controller's view to the window in the Segue class:

```
class JFTransitionControllerSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let defaultTransitionDuration : CFTimeInterval = 1.5

        if let dvc = self.destination as? TransitionController {
            dvc.prepareTransitionIn()
        }
        else {
            // Default transition
            self.destination.view.alpha = 0
        }
        if let svc = self.source as? TransitionController {
            svc.prepareTransitionOut()
            svc.performTransitionOut(){ () in

                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(self.destination.view, aboveSubview: self.source.view)
                if let dvc = self.destination as? TransitionController {
                    dvc.performTransitionIn(){ () in
                        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Default transition for the destination controller
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: defaultTransitionDuration, animations: {
                        self.destination.view.alpha = 1
                    }) { (Finished) in
                        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Default transition for the source controller
            UIView.animate(withDuration: defaultTransitionDuration, animations: {
                self.source.view.alpha = 0
            }) { (Finished) in
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(self.destination.view, aboveSubview: self.source.view)
                if let dvc = self.destination as? TransitionController {
                    dvc.performTransitionIn(){ () in
                        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Default transition for the destination controller
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: defaultTransitionDuration, animations: {
                        self.destination.view.alpha = 1
                    }) { (Finished) in
                        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```